# Does reading from xml file keep app small?

Tags: android, xml, memory-management, xml-parsing

I am currently making an educational app that will need to have alot of text . I was wondering if reading from an xml file with the data use less memory than creating various strings of populating numerous textviews .I would like the app to be as small as possible like the physics solver app which has tons of text with images and is still 4mb large .If not, how can I put alot of text and still keep my app small?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking about the "footprint" of the app (size of the APK - not size in memory necessarily), then things are little different.

First, when you say "XML" I assume you mean the Android "values" XML for storing Strings. Random XML depends on the XMLNS (the NameSpace) and attributes, etc. It can bloat fast.

For Android res XML files, the compiler will create a static reference to each String in the "R" file (resources) that you will later reference using "R.string.myString". This adds to the footprint, but only minimally.

Second, in bytecode static Strings will not have that reference, but they do have a "enumerated and indexed constant pools" as described in the docs here: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html

So either way you end up with a static reference to the String. Once in memory, they will essentially all be treated the same. For XML, the `Resources` object will `getString` which creates a `CharSequence`. For static variables, it might be a bit faster because the bytecode identifies it as a java.lang.String and instantiates it that way. But performance for either of these will be more dependent on platform implementations, thread and core queuing and other things that have nothing to do with you code - because both are really, really fast.

Also, you should consider that either of these solutions will allow a very large amount of text to be stored - most books contain about 400,000 - 500,000 characters (https://www.quora.com/How-many-characters-of-text-letters-are-in-an-average-book). So most of your footprint will come from compiling your java project (framework) and then images, if you choose to have them. A 500kb text string is a book. A 500kb image is one semi-decent image. (When they say a picture is worth a thousand words - in software, it's more like a hundred thousand or more :) ).

Answer (score 0):

Well, using xml means less space but slower loading of the app, using Strings means a little more ram usage but Faster loading. Meaning if you launch the app it might delay with the xml for a second or two, but with Strings it will load with almost no delay. I would say xml, it means a little more mb but it also means less phone ram meaning it could run on any phone.

Answer (score 0):

No, XML takes up more space both in memory and disk space.  However, if you have XML file you don't have to read the whole thing either.

If you have a large data set, and you're worried about space for the app, I would have the data as a set of SQL database creation scripts and SQL inserts and then compress it and store it as part of your app.

Then on initial load you can extract it and load it up in the [SQLLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) so you can do lookups and release the data from memory when you're no longer using it.